# Call script or recognize, when long running script ends ahead of time

Tags: php, sphider

I'm using Sphider to index some content on a network-shared drive. When I have a very large set of directories/files, scripts take a long time and sometimes it ends ahead of time. Then I can the script again, and it will continue where it ends.

So I'm curious, if there is a possibility to have some sort of callback, which will recognize, if scripts ends prematurely or not. I found [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) but, according to the documentation, it can only recognize `exit()` or function finish, so it wont solve my particular issue.

Alternatively, is there any way to determine if scripts ended correctly, or prematurely?

Comment: If the script ends because of a PHP configuration, then it is not possible to have it continue to do the other task you're asking.  By the way, doing that would still count in the same configuration limitations.

Comment: @JuliePelletier yes, im aware of server limitations. I tried to raise them, but propably blocked. But i think, that when some scripts running and it will execute next script, timeout resets. Or am i wrong?

Comment: No it doesn't.  When a script calls another script, the script duration continues.

Comment: @JuliePelletier ah sorry, my mistake. So i extend a question a bit, if there is posibility to recognize if scripts end prematurely or not... so maybe it isnt so offtopic

Comment: No.  The only way you could for example output a message that it's about to timeout is to time it yourself and stop processing to produce that output before it does timeout.